# MATLAB: Cannot properly evaluate function using input vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I am trying to pass a vector into a function, and evaluate the vector over a piecewise function.  When I run the code below, I am only returned a single number rather than a vector.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
t[-5:1:50]
velocity(t)

function [v] = velocity( t )

%This function takes vector 't' and evaluates a velocity over a given
%piecewise function

if t>=0 & t<=8
v=10*t^2-5*t;

elseif t>=8 & t<=16
v=624-5*t;

elseif t>=16 & t<=26
v= 36*t+12*(t-16)^2;

elseif t>26
v=2136*exp(-0.1*(t-26));
else t<0

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you elevate a vector to the square, you are performing a scalar product with itself.

Replace `t^2` with `t.^2` for element-wise operators.

Do the same for `(t-16).^2`.

All the other operators should fall automatically into the element wise case but you can add points before them to be sure.

And, furthermore, the conditions as you have wrote them apply to a `t` as a scalar value. You can get the researched effect by doing the following:

Instead of

```
if cond1:
    v = something
elif cond2:
    v = something_else
```

Do

```
indices1 = (cond1)  % where cond1 is t < 10 for example
indices2 = (cond2)  % and cond2 is t >= 10
v[indices1] = something
v[indices2] = something_else
```

I hope you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I realized that the operators wouldn't work because they evaluate the vector as a whole rather than each individual element.

I used some of your psuedocode with the addition of a for loop to pass/evaluate each element.

Comment: No probs, this place is made for people to help each other. The pseudocode was intended for the vector-valued `t` actually. A for loop is not necessary in this case. Indeed, `t < 10` will return the array of indices where the value of `t` is less than 10. You can then those indices to set the values of `v` accordingly. Handling all the cases will allow you to build up the entire `v` vector. I'm sorry I wasn't clear about this.